# terraform failed to query available provider packages

Tags: terraform

I'm new to terraform.

Trying to create local file. My main.tf looks like this:

```
resource local_file sample_res {
  filename = "sample.txt"
  content = "I learn terraform"
}
```

And I get this error:

> C:\tf-workspace\first-tf-script>terraform init
>
> Initializing the backend...
>
> Initializing provider plugins...
>
> - Finding latest version of hashicorp/local... ╷ │ Error: Failed to query available provider packages │ │ Could not retrieve the list of
>   available versions for provider hashicorp/local: could not connect to
>   registry.terraform.io: Failed to request discovery document: Get
>   "https://registry.terraform.io/.well-known/terraform.json": dial tcp:
>   lookup       │ registry.terraform.io: no such host ╵

I try to google this error, but a little bit didn't understand.

Comment: It seems you have a connection problem, check your proxy or your firewall please

Comment: @YCF_L thanks a lot, yeah it was problem with my work VPN. Now it works. You can post this as an answer in case somebody will have same problem.

Comment: It's OK it can happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was problem due to VPN.
Than I try to use terraform without VPN it start working.